# Deleting Git Repository Gitolite?

Tags: git, version-control, gitolite

I am wondering what the proper way is to delete a repository when using gitolite.

Is there anything else I have to do besides delete the repository from the server and remove all configurations related to the repository I am removing?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Nope! That's all you have to do!

Answer (score 90):

Deleting the repository from the server and removing all configurations is all you have to do.

Quoting from [the manual](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin.html#removingrenaming-a-repo):

> Removing a repo is not so straightforward. You certainly must remove
>   the appropriate lines from the conf/gitolite.conf file, but gitolite
>   will not automatically delete the repo from the server. You have to
>   log on to the server and do the dirty deed yourself :-)
>
> It is best to make the change in the conf file, push it, and then go
>   to the server and do what you need to.

Comment: +1 for referring to the manual and quote the suggested steps.

Comment: Is there anything else that needs to be done apart from editing the conf file and deleting the repository folder from the server?

Comment: @Stan Well, to be precise, you would have to `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` the config file to the remote repository after you are done editing.

Comment: +1 for explaining ***why*** "that's all you have to do", instead of plainly saying "that's all you have to do".

Answer (score 6):

Actually there is another more formal way to do this through the Apis.
This is a more practical way when giving away to users the privilige to create their own repos (wild repos).

This requires:

- Admin enables the D command by removing the appropriate commented line (on the server) in $HOME/.gitolite.rc
- Unlocking the repository (safety procedure) "ssh gitolite@hostname D unlock reponame"
- Deleteing the repository with "ssh gitolite@hostname D rm reponame"

Some simple documentation can be found in [the Gitolite docs](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/wild.html#deleting-a-wild-repo) but the documentation is better in the book "Gitolite Essentials".

Comment: Isn't this just for "wild" repos?

Comment: Actually it seems to work for both but is sorely needed when create privs are given as freely as when using wild repos.

Comment: +1, Just small addition- before you do it you need to make sure to uncomment 'D' command in .gitolite.rc file in Gitolite host so this command is enabled